# React dynamically created child component not receiving new props

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to follow React's "Stateless children, stateful parent" ideology, and it works perfectly... until I start creating children dynamically, that is.

Here is a simplified version of my code (CoffeeScript + JSX) that illustrates my predicament:

```
@FormBlock = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    fields: [], editMode: false

  toggle: ->
    @setState editMode: !@state.editMode

  addChild: ->
    child = `<EditableText key={Date.now()} text="FAILS" editMode={this.state.editMode}/>`
    items = @state.fields.concat child
    @setState fields: items

  render: ->
    `<div>
        <a onClick={this.toggle}>Change Mode</a><br/>
        <a onClick={this.addChild}>Add Child</a><br/>
        <EditableText text="WORKS" editMode={this.state.editMode}/><br/>
        {this.state.fields}
    </div>`


@EditableText = React.createClass
  render: ->
    if @props.editMode
      `<input className="editable" defaultValue={this.props.text}/>`
    else
      `<span className="editable">{this.props.text}</span>`
```

In this example, component `<FormBlock>` will initially contain no `fields` and its `editMode=false`. When `editMode` is changed to `true` by clicking the `Change Mode` button, the content of the `<EditableText>` component will change from `<span>` to `<input>` so that a user can make changes to it.

This works perfectly for the dummy component contained in `<FormBlock>`'s `render` method (i.e. `<EditableText text="WORKS".../>`), but this does not work for the children. I have tested that upon creation, every child of type `<EditableText>` will receive its initial `props`, but when `state.editMode` is modified, all of the children remain unchanged (I have verified that `componentWillReceiveProps` does not fire on the children, but it does on the dummy element).

I am at my wits' end trying to solve this problem. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the result of calling the EditableText is saved in the component state. If you want to dynamically render child components based on state, do so in the render method instead:

```js
@FormBlock = React.createClass
  getInitialState: ->
    fields: [], editMode: false

  toggle: ->
    @setState editMode: !@state.editMode

  addChild: ->
    items = @state.fields.concat {}
    @setState fields: items

  render: ->
    `<div>
        <a onClick={this.toggle}>Change Mode</a><br/>
        <a onClick={this.addChild}>Add Child</a><br/>
        <EditableText text="WORKS" editMode={this.state.editMode}/><br/>
        { this.state.fields.map @renderChild }
    </div>`

    renderChild: ->
        `<EditableText
            key={Date.now()}
            text="FAILS"
            editMode={this.state.editMode}/>`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work (i.e. children are still not being updated when the parent is updated). The `addChild` in your version does not append the new child to the list. As for your suggestion to render children in the parent's render method, my code snippet `{this.state.fields}` already does exactly that - using the `map` method is essentially the same, but more verbose.

Comment: You're partially right. The big difference between your approach and the one explained above is the fact that in my response the child components are re-rendered when the parent's render method is called, whereas in your case the result of calling the child components' render method is memoized in the parent's state and is simply being recalled instead of re-rendered.

Comment: The reason why my example isn't working is because you're using the current timestamp as a key. Calling the renderChild method takes a fraction of a millisecond. As such the provided timestamp is the same for all editableText instances and React's reconcilliation algorithm filters out all elements with a duplicate key, leaving you with only a single instance of the EditableText component. A working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1eur6xkd/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed example!!! It finally helped me figure this out. It looks like I didn't understand your code at first, but the second example you posted cleared things up. :)